# Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine (Rootless)

Tags: ubuntu, docker

OS: Ubuntu 22.04

Docker: 25.0.1

I'm following instructions to setup rootless docker https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/ but I'm getting the following error:

```
$ dockerd-rootless-setuptool.sh install
[INFO] Creating /home/pc/.config/systemd/user/docker.service
[INFO] starting systemd service docker.service
+ systemctl --user start docker.service
+ sleep 3
+ systemctl --user --no-pager --full status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine (Rootless)
     Loaded: loaded (/home/pc/.config/systemd/user/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2024-01-27 17:33:44 EST; 758ms ago
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com/go/rootless/
    Process: 145135 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd-rootless.sh (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 145135 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 6ms

Jan 27 17:33:44 dev dockerd-rootless.sh[145135]: + [ -z  ]
Jan 27 17:33:44 dev dockerd-rootless.sh[145135]: + command -v vpnkit
Jan 27 17:33:44 dev dockerd-rootless.sh[145135]: + echo Either slirp4netns (>= v0.4.0) or vpnkit needs to be installed
Jan 27 17:33:44 dev dockerd-rootless.sh[145135]: Either slirp4netns (>= v0.4.0) or vpnkit needs to be installed
Jan 27 17:33:44 dev dockerd-rootless.sh[145135]: + exit 1
Jan 27 17:33:44 dev systemd[2053]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 27 17:33:44 dev systemd[2053]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
+ set +x
[ERROR] Failed to start docker.service. Run `journalctl -n 20 --no-pager --user --unit docker.service` to show the error log.
[ERROR] Before retrying installation, you might need to uninstall the current setup: `/usr/bin/dockerd-rootless-setuptool.sh uninstall -f ; /usr/bin/rootlesskit rm -rf /home/pc/.local/share/docker`
```

The error log:

```
$ journalctl -n 20 --no-pager --user --unit docker.service
Jan 27 17:33:46 dev dockerd-rootless.sh[145142]: + :
Jan 27 17:33:46 dev dockerd-rootless.sh[145142]: + : builtin
Jan 27 17:33:46 dev dockerd-rootless.sh[145142]: + : auto
Jan 27 17:33:46 dev dockerd-rootless.sh[145142]: + : auto
Jan 27 17:33:46 dev dockerd-rootless.sh[145142]: + net=
Jan 27 17:33:46 dev dockerd-rootless.sh[145142]: + mtu=
Jan 27 17:33:46 dev dockerd-rootless.sh[145142]: + [ -z  ]
Jan 27 17:33:46 dev dockerd-rootless.sh[145142]: + command -v slirp4netns
Jan 27 17:33:46 dev dockerd-rootless.sh[145142]: + [ -z  ]
Jan 27 17:33:46 dev dockerd-rootless.sh[145142]: + command -v vpnkit
Jan 27 17:33:46 dev dockerd-rootless.sh[145142]: + echo Either slirp4netns (>= v0.4.0) or vpnkit needs to be installed
Jan 27 17:33:46 dev dockerd-rootless.sh[145142]: Either slirp4netns (>= v0.4.0) or vpnkit needs to be installed
Jan 27 17:33:46 dev dockerd-rootless.sh[145142]: + exit 1
Jan 27 17:33:46 dev systemd[2053]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 27 17:33:46 dev systemd[2053]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 27 17:33:49 dev systemd[2053]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Jan 27 17:33:49 dev systemd[2053]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine (Rootless).
Jan 27 17:33:49 dev systemd[2053]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jan 27 17:33:49 dev systemd[2053]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 27 17:33:49 dev systemd[2053]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine (Rootless).
```

The logs are not providing any useful information. What can I do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the logs and this issue(https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/41781), it's sufficient to install the missing dependency with 'apt install slirp4netns'. It should be included in docker-ce-rootless-extras, but you can also do it yourself.